# Renicing complex multithreaded applications in Linux

Tags: linux, process

Applications (especially big Java and C++ ones) often shows up as multiple lines in `htop`, each have separate PID and separate nice level. Also application can spawn a lot of child processes (like as in `aptitude update`), so I need to affect both parent one (to make new children have new priority) and child ones (to bring the effect immediately, not after the child terminates)

How can I apply "renice" or "ionice" or "schedtool" to already launched big application?

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the PID of the topmost process, and remember it.

2) Get all processes with PPID of a remembered PID, and remember their PIDs

3) repeat step 2 until there are no new PIDs.

4) For each PID, apply command to that process.

Shouldn't be too difficult in your favourite language.

Comment: Are there already implemented things? I asked at SO if I would going to implement it myself.

Comment: I used the command `ps xHo ppid,pid,args | grep -v grep | grep firefox` and every thread appears to have the same pid and ppid. I tried a couple of variants of that before doing it manually; none of the subthreads appear to be actual children. It's been *7 years* since you posted this, so I assume something (everything) changed; I wouldn't touch a post this old if it weren't so high in the search results. FWIW the parent is my panel and the grandparent is upstart - not much help there. (Ubuntu x64 + xfce4 + FF 55.02 x64)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fully robust solution, but in many cases the set of target processes will be a process group. If `$parent` is the pid of the parent process, the following command lists the pids of the processes in the group:

```
ps -eo pgrp:1=,pid:1= |sed -n "s/^$parent //p"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but since this is what came up when I searched for the same thing, I figured I'd post my solution ([also posted in this gist in case I update it](https://gist.github.com/2646996))

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This can be run simply by passing it the outputs from pgrep:
# my_renice $(pgrep application)
#
# You may also want to use pgrep to find more complex 
#    processes based on arguments
# my_renice $(pgrep -f "bash.*$name")

function my_renice(){
  newnice=10
  pid=$1

  # Return if pid not found
  if [ -z $pid ]; then return; fi

  # Renice pid right away in case we spawn more children
  renice $newnice $pid

  # Find children pids
  children=$(pgrep -d ' ' -P $pid)

  # Loop through children
  for i in $children; do my_renice $i; done
}
```

Comment: Probably won't match threads (visible in `/proc/$pid/tasks/`).

Answer (score 0):

Note that CPU niceness is inherited by child processes. So just renice the parent (or start it using `nice`); the child processes will get the same niceness.

If children are already running when you do this, you will of course have to renice them separately. But in practice I found that there are typically just a few processes that really hog the CPU; I renice those, and the parent process.

Comment: How to renice or (re-`schedtool`) already running compilaion? I want both to renive current compiler process and further processes.

Comment: @Vi: Renice the parent process of the compilation (usually that will be `make` or whatever you use), then renice the children if necessary (compiler runs are usually very short, so might not be necessary).

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo renice -n num $(pidof processname)
```

Comment: Can you explain how/why this works?

Comment: After using `renice -n 19 $(pidof simpleuser)` I use: `cat /proc/$(pidof simpleuser)/task/*/stat |  awk '{print $19}'` and get:
`
19
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
`

Comment: Simple, $(pidof processname), such as $(pidof X) or $(pidof compiz) or $(pidof firefox) will grab the PIDs of all processes behind that process and feed that as the argument for sudo renice -n <>. Renice only accepts PIDs, not process names, so you have to use $(pidof <>) to get the PIDs.